# I have problems with autoload.php when trying to conect Parse with php

Tags: php, parse-platform

I just installed the parse SDK for php and did it fine. My problem is the configuration in `autoload.php`. I'm really confused about that file. What is expected to be there?

The code that is written is:

```
<?php
//autoload.php @generated by Composer
require_conce__DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInit453dfd95ed88696b0c3517290ff38581::getLoader();
```

And it's supossed to be:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
use Parse/ParseClient;
ParseClient::initialize('some_crypted_link', 'some_crypted_link',
'some_crypted_link');
```

I tried to replace everything, just a bit, and a large etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your slash in in the wrong direction for PHP namespaces.

Try `use Parse\ParseClient;`

You want to use the namespace declaration at the top of any script where you use the `ParseClient` (the code you're thinking should be the `autoload.php` is the code you use to use the `ParseClient`).

Your autoload.php looks fine.